# Align Multiple Chart Areas

Tags: vb.net, charts, mschart

I have several charts that I would like to align on the `InnerPlotPosition`.

As you can see in picture 1 when I try to position it with `InnerPlotPosition`, I cannot get the Y-axis to align when I try to plot the chart area myself and turning auto position off. Picture 2 is the desired output

See code.

```
     '.ChartAreas("chr" + type).InnerPlotPosition.Auto = False
        ' .ChartAreas("chr" + type).InnerPlotPosition.Width = 80
        '.ChartAreas("chr" + type).InnerPlotPosition.Height = 90
```

> Picture 1

[image]

> Picture 2

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The absolute positioning of elements in a chart is a royal pain in you know. You need to take care of the following

- Text elements are NOT part of the chart area bounds. Therefore you need to plan in additional space for axes titles and numbers.
- All values are percentage values of the current chart size. So if your chart is 200px wide and you set the .Left property to 50 it means location 100. That can become very frustrating if you want to make the chart sizable.

To transform a percentage value to an absolute value you need some calculation. For example you want to have a constant border around your chart area in pixels you can do the following:

First set the values of the variables defining the size of the border on each side (in pixels):

```
Dim ChartBorderLeft as Integer = 100 'Pixels on the left
Dim ChartBorderRight as Integer = 100 'Pixels on the right
Dim ChartBorderTop as Integer = 100 'Pixels on the top
Dim ChartBorderBottom as Integer = 100 'Pixels on the bottom
```

Then you adjust the percentages that define the location and size of the InnerPlotPosition in the the code based on the current chart size and the border variables.

```
 chart.ChartAreas(0).InnerPlotPosition.X = CSng(ChartBorderLeft / chart.Width) * 100 'Left border
 chart.ChartAreas(0).InnerPlotPosition.Y = CSng(ChartBorderTop / chart.Height) * 100 'Top Border
 chart.ChartAreas(0).InnerPlotPosition.Width = CSng((chart.Width - ChartBorderLeft - ChartBorderRight) / chart.Width) * 100
 chart.ChartAreas(0).InnerPlotPosition.Height = CSng((chart.Height - ChartBorderTop - ChartBorderBottom) / chart.Height) * 100
```

`chart` is the chart object you want to modify. The code is only thought of for one single chart area in the chart. I moved away from the idea of having multiple chart areas and instead used multiple charts where I needed it.
`ChartBorderLeft`, `ChartBorderRight` and so on are the borders on each side in pixels. The location of the axes are the bounds of the `InnerPlotPosition` so it lines up nicely if the borders are the same size afterwards.
For title and numbers you should plan in around 100px borders. You can also place the code in the chart's resize event handler to have the plot position adjusted when the chart's size changes.

Comment: How do I assign the pixels too chartBorderLeft, ChartBorderRight,InnerPlotPosition ?

Comment: Just set ChartBorderLeft and so on before you call the code above. They are just integer variables. The code above is a part of changes I made for a chart control in my application. The class inherits from the chart class and adds properties `ChartBorderLeft` and so on so I can just set these directly in the designer. That's why they are not defined in the sample above. I will change that.

Comment: Just have one more question CSng(ChartBorderLeft / chart.Width) * 100 when I try to do this is complaining that  "operator '/'is not defined for types 'integer' and 'system.web.UIWebControls.unit'"

Comment: Are you using Winforms? Is the chart you are manipulation named "chart"? Are you using the `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart` control? My answer is based on this control.

Comment: Yes using winforms and yes it's named chart and I'm not using **System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart** because it's doesn't exist for instead using **System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting**. Using microsoft visual studios express 2012 for web.

Comment: Oh I see. Try to define ChartBorderLeft and so on as the same type `system.web.UIWebControls.unit`. In a browser the sizes are (I guess) not defined per pixel but in stuff like device independent units (more like WPF) to make the sizing platform independent. The principle is the same though, you just need to calculate the sums/ratios in the same way as above, only for the Units and not for pixels. I can't really test it here, though.

Answer (score 2):

chart1.ChartAreas[a].AlignWithChartArea = chart1.ChartAreas[a - 1].Name;